# submitting a form with multiple different buttons

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make a form that has three different submit buttons or inputs. I read that to do that I have to provide a name and a value attribute to the button. I already tried the button tag and input tag. But when I try to submit them and then print the POST request from within Django. nothing is printed. Only the csrf token is included with the POST request.

This is the code I am trying. It only works when there is an input tag other than the submit type. but then I can't seperate them because any button will post everything in the form. THanks!

```html
    <input type="submit" name="first_choice" value="first"  class="btn btn-danger" >
    <input type="submit" name="first_choice" value="second" class="btn btn-info" >
    <input type="submit" name="first_choice" value="third"  class="btn btn-success" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<input type="submit" name="choice1" value="first"  class="btn btn-danger" >
<input type="submit" name="choice2" value="second" class="btn btn-info" >
<input type="submit" name="choice3" value="third"  class="btn btn-success" >
```

In the view

```
if 'choice1' in request.POST: ...
```

Comment: <QueryDict: {}> still empty.